# LazyColumn with constraints between component in different items

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a `LazyColumn` with items as `Row` containing `LinearProgressIndicator` and `Text`.

**Sample Screenshot**

[image]

**Given conditions,**

1. All text is aligned to the end.
2. I am using `LazyColumn` as there are many items and the list will be scrollable.

**Requirement**
How to make the `LinearProgressIndicator` as wide as possible BUT it should have the same width across Rows.

i.e. In the given screenshot, I want all the `LinearProgressIndicator` to be as wide as the `LinearProgressIndicator` in the `Row` containing text "Text 2 with lot more content".

**Constraints,**

1. Can not have hardcoded width for the progress or the text.
2. I have data for all the items. (No pagination)

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun LazyColumnProgress() {
    val data = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", 0.30F),
        Pair("Text 1 with more", 0.25F),
        Pair("Text 2 with lot more content", 0.20F),
        Pair("Text 3", 0.14F),
        Pair("Text 4", 0.5F),
        Pair("Text 5", 0.3F),
        Pair("Text 6", 0.1F),
        Pair("Text 7", 0.1F),
        Pair("Text 8", 0.09F),
        Pair("Text 9", 0.01F),
    )

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        items(data) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                    progress = it.second,
                    strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1F),
                )
                Text(
                    text = it.first,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                    ),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.End),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure texts with `TextMeasurer` to get longest text width. minus horizontal paddings which are 8.dp twice for both sides. To get width of the total width you can use BoxWithConstraints and get the width for LinearProgressIndicator.

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyColumnProgress() {
    val data = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", 0.30F),
        Pair("Text 1 with more", 0.25F),
        Pair("Text 2 with lot more content", 0.20F),
        Pair("Text 3", 0.14F),
        Pair("Text 4", 0.5F),
        Pair("Text 5", 0.3F),
        Pair("Text 6", 0.1F),
        Pair("Text 7", 0.1F),
        Pair("Text 8", 0.09F),
        Pair("Text 9", 0.01F),
    )

    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

    val maxTextWidth = data.maxOf {
        textMeasurer.measure(it.first).size.width
    }


    BoxWithConstraints {

        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val indicatorWidth = with(density) {
            (maxWidth - maxTextWidth).toDp() -32.dp
        }
        
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            items(items = data) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                ) {
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                        progress = it.second,
                        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(indicatorWidth),
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Text(
                        text = it.first,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```